# Linq to sql and C#, WPF select problem

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

i have two table Rooms, BookedRooms

want to `select BookedRooms.RoomID(which is more than one) than select Rooms.SizeX and Room.SizeX from Rooms where Room.ID == BoookedRooms.RoomID`

Than Filter Room.ID list and leave only `ID which != BookedRooms.ID`
Please help

Comment: Are you sure you want those two tables? It looks like Booked should be an attribute/column of Room.

Comment: yes. im sure bookedRooms is another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess?

```
from bookedRooms in db.BookedRooms
from rooms in db.Rooms
where bookedRooms.RoomId == rooms.ID && rooms.ID != bookedRooms.ID
select new { SizeX = rooms.SizeX, SizeY = rooms.SizeY }
```

Answer (score -1):

So you want a list of rooms that are not booked right?

```
var availableRooms = Rooms.Where(r => !BookedRooms.Any(b => b.RoomID == r.ID);
```

Comment: its doesnot work for me when i wright room and then dot there is every column of table but where does not

Comment: @Acid, will mine says "Rooms" not "Room". You question does not make it clear what are the names of your collection and entities. You seem to already have the answer so I guess it doesn't matter any more